# How to merge 2 datatables into one with same number of rows as 1st datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to merge or Union 2 datatables into 1 with same number of rows as first datatable.

This is using c# and asp.net

```
  Dataset ds = new Dataset(); //Ds has 2 tables with same number of rows.
  DataTable dtAll = new DataTable();
  dtAll = ds.Tables[0].Copy();
  dtAll.Merge(ds.Tables[1], true);
```

For example: Sl.no  Date   Amount Sold  in first datable

Amount Collected in Datatable 2
The final Datatable should be sl.no   Date   AmountSold   AmountCollected with union.

The Amount SOld and Collected is from the same day.. I hope i am clear.

When i use the above Merge(), it merges into double the rows. What am i missing?!

Thank you!!

Comment: What do you expect as a result when you "merge" two datatables? Sample data and expected output would help

Comment: The word you are looking for is `join` not merge i believe.

Comment: Where the data coming from to DataSet? can you share some more code?

Comment: lets say you have table Foo with columns A and B, and Bar with columns  C and D, are you saying you want a new table that has columns A, B, C, and D with row 1 from each table Foo and Bar as row 1 in the new table?

Comment: You made it simple. Thank you DMoses! You are right!!!

Comment: you should join them with linq then put it into a DataTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems what you want to do is JOIN the two tables into one and bring the results, for this you need a Foreign Key of some sort, a unique column that will allow reference both tables (in your case im assuming 'SI.No'

try this SQL statement when you create the Dataset()

```
SELECT a.*, b.AmountCollected from [table1] a 
INNER JOIN [table2] b INTO a.Sino=b.sino  'or whatever column name has the same value as [table1]
```

that should get you the result you are looking for unless IM not comprehending correctly what you are looking for

Comment: It seems he wants to do the operation in code (c#) rather than at the SQL level.

Comment: This is quite simple in SQL. I should have known this before! This method will solve a lot of my time in future. Thank you very much!